# FluentValidation predicate validator doesn't work

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, fluentvalidation

I have model class:

```
[FluentValidation.Attributes.Validator(typeof(CrcValidator))]
public class CrcModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Binary value")]
    public string binaryValue { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Generator")]
    public string generator { get; set; }
}
```

And validator class with predicate:

```
public class CrcValidator : AbstractValidator<CrcModel>
{
    public CrcValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.binaryValue)
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Binary value is required")
            .Matches(@"(0|1)*").WithMessage("This value is not valid binary value");

        RuleFor(x => x.generator)
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Generator is required")
            .Matches(@"(0|1)*").WithMessage("Generator must be valid binary value")
            .Must(CompareLength).WithMessage("Length must be lesser than length of binary value - 1");
    }

    private bool CompareLength(CrcModel model, string value)
    {
        return model.binaryValue.Length - 1 > model.generator.Length;
    }
}
```

I placed breakpoint inside the CompareLength function and every value is properly read from form. The problem is that my form passes validation even though my predicate function returns false. NotEmpty and Matches rules work perfectly fine only Must seems to be ommited.

**EDIT**

jQuery for submit button (of type "button"):

```
$(function () {
$("#Button1").click(function () {
    var form = $("#Form1");
    if ($(form).valid()) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'Compute',
            data: $(form).serialize(),
            success: function (result) {
                $("#remainder").val(result.remainder);
                $("#signal").val(result.signal);
            }
        });
    }
}); 
});
```

Controller action handling form submit:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Compute([Bind(Include = "binaryValue,generator")] CrcModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            model.remainder = ComputeFrame(model.binaryValue, model.generator);
            model.signal = model.binaryValue + model.remainder;
        }

        return Json(new { remainder = model.remainder, signal = model.signal });
    }
```

Validation from Must rule works on server side but the message doesn't show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** After a few comments, the validations defined in all calls to `Must` in FluentValidation are only executed on the server. There is no JavaScript equivalent to arbitrary C# code. FluentValidation rules in C# get translated by the MVC framework to various HTML5 `data-*` attributes on the form field tags in HTML, which jQuery Validate reads during client side validation. Since there is no way to translate validation rules defined in predicates (delegate methods) to HTML5 `data-*` attributes, those validation rules are only enforceable server side.

**Edit #2:** Seeing as the `Must` validation is triggered by an AJAX call, you need to do a couple things:

1. Set the HTTP Status code to a non-200 response to trigger the error handling mechanism in jQuery. Plus, set the HTTP status to 422 (Unprocessable Entity)

   ```
   HttpPost]
   [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
   public ActionResult Compute([Bind(Include = "binaryValue,generator")] CrcModel model)
   {
       if (ModelState.IsValid)
       {
           model.remainder = ComputeFrame(model.binaryValue, model.generator);
           model.signal = model.binaryValue + model.remainder;

           return Json(new { remainder = model.remainder, signal = model.signal });
       }
       else
       {
           Response.StatusCode = 422;

           return Json(new { errors = ModelState.Errors });
       }
   }
   ```
2. Change the jQuery.ajax call:

   ```
   $(function () {
       $("#Button1").click(function () {
           var form = $("#Form1");
           if ($(form).valid()) {
               $.ajax({
                   type: 'POST',
                   url: 'Compute',
                   data: $(form).serialize(),
                   success: function (result) {
                       $("#remainder").val(result.remainder);
                       $("#signal").val(result.signal);
                   },
                   error: function(xhr) {
                       if (xhr.status == 422) {
                           var errors = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

                           console.log(errors);
                       }
                   }
               });
           }
       }); 
   });
   ```

An alternative would be to just render a Partial that displays one or more error messages as HTML, then set that HTML in a DIV and show the DIV tag.

Comment: Hm. Strange. I've used this sort of thing with ASP.NET MVC 4 and it works fine. So `ModelState.IsValid` is reporting `true`?

Comment: Oh dear, actually I forgot to check ModelState.IsValid in my controller and I assumed that if given message isn't showing then the predicate isn't working. After updating my controller with ModelState.IsValid validation from predicate works indeed but the message still doesn't show up. Any idea what can be the issue with message?

Comment: Also I check whether my form is valid with form.valid() in my js before calling my controller from ajax so if form.valid() on client side returns true and ModelState.IsValid on server side returns false it means that Must rule works only on server side. Can this be somewhat helpful with the message issue?

Comment: That's exactly the issue! :) Any predicates passed in to the `Must` method are only invoked on the server side, not the client side. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Alright. But how can I get the message to show up after server side validation? (I'm using Html.ValidationMessageFor helpers)

Comment: If you are doing this via AJAX, then you'll have to process the HTTP response somehow. Can you update your question with more information? Are you using AJAX? What's the controller look like and what is it returning (HTML, JSON, etc).

Comment: Edited with Jquery and controller action

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56709/discussion-between-greg-burghardt-and-cheerup).

Comment: Hi @Cheerup, did you ever manage to get these messages to show up in your ValidationMessageFor helpers?

Comment: @CiaranGallagher: The `data-valmsg-for` attribute on the `<span>` tags generated by ValidationMessageFor contain the name of the form field (or the Id, I forget right offhand). You can use that naming pattern to associate keys in the model errors with those validation messages on the client, which is basically what the MVC framework does while rendering a razor template server-side.